# Is there a way we can create user interactive content within amp stories?

Tags: amp-story, amp-bind

I am building an amp story where I need to take user input as choice. Let say there are 3 buttons `Button 1`, `Button 2` and `Button 3`. If user clicks `Button 1` content for `choice 1` would be shown and similarly for other buttons.

I was trying to use `AMP.setState` for that. It works on a plain AMP page, but when amp story is added to the page, it doesn't work.

Here is the [code for the above mentioned experiment](https://jsfiddle.net/mutafaf/5xmte8an/1/)

Please have a look and propose some suitable solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amp-story` is not compatible with `amp-bind`.

Stories have an experimental feature under development called "branching" that allows user interactivity by splitting content state across different pages of the same story (see the [work in progress documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/d16b3d82d6d009204d39128712b255010643a119/extensions/amp-story/amp-story.md#experimental-feature-branching)).

In your example, you would need to create separate pages of the story for the user to land on for if they've clicked `Button 1`, `Button 2`, or `Button 3`, respectively.